# "NVIDIA driver 461.09 is known to have some issues with DaVinci Resolve"

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I use Windows 10. After I clicked to open DaVinci Resolve 17, I got this Warning.

[image]

Then I tried [Chris' Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-bOWyFYjOI), but GeForce Experience turned out barren to me, and lacks all those features shown in the YouTube video.

[image]

Edit this post if you know which, but another YouTube video recommended unticking my NVIDIA GeForce as follows.

[image]

But when I clicked "Save", I got another Error!

[image]

Comment: Yeah, you can’t disable your Nvidia card since that would leave you without a GPU, the Intel iGPU is frayed out and disable due the existence of your dGPU.  It doesn’t appear you clicked on the hamburger button (the three dots) but the profile icon

Comment: Why not just download another driver? https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Comment: @codidact - The reason your not getting a studio driver option is because your GPU doesn’t support them.

Comment: @Ramhound So practically, what do I do? Use another program?

Comment: @Tetsujin But how do I productively know which other driver will work with DaVinci Resolve? I don't want to trial-and-error each drive on that website!!!

Comment: @codidact - You could downgrade to a different version that doesn’t have the check.  If you have any doubts that a Studio Nvidia driver doesn’t exist you can check the Nvidia website